# Yii PHP Framework and CActiveForm. Cannot get correct URL for my action

Tags: php, yii

I have **actionTest** in my **SiteController**.

```
public function actionTest(){
        echo '<h1>My newest action work correctly!</h1>';
    }
```

It's work when I try to use www.example.com/?r=site/test. But in my CActiveFrom I get 404.

```
<div class="form">
        <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'test-form-inquiry',
            'action'=>getUrl('site/test'),
            'method'=>'post',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
            'enableClientValidation'=>false,
            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')
        )); ?>
</div>
```

Please tell me where my mistake and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside your CActiveForm options:

```
'action'=> Yii::app()->createUrl("site/test")
```

Or:

```
'action'=> Yii::app()->baseUrl."?r=site/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put simply,
 'action'=>array('site/test'),